# At what level of detail does God lead His children?

Tags: prayer, christian-living

It seems that some people worry and pray about every aspect of their life, while others only sweat the big stuff. For example, I doubt any believer does not pray about whether they should marry a certain person or not. But for less significant matters, some pray about what God's will is and others just make a decision without prayer.

Should you pray about what career you should choose? About what book you should buy? At what point should you just make a decision?

Does the Bible indicate an answer to this question?

Note: I found a similar question *[here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/does-the-holy-spirit-ever-choose-not-to-lead/8390#8390)*.

Comment: do you have a particular perspective you are looking for here? Different people, and different groups will have rather disparate opinions on this subject

Comment: @waxeagle - wondering if a biblical argument can be made for a certain range of detail, or is the level of detail just personal and left up to the whims and preferences of the individual. I have not formulated an answer myself. My instinct is God just wants us holy and He let's us decide most of the rest. Yet out of habit I seem to 'check-in' with Him on a level of detail that almost seems embarrassing to admit. Am curious what other views might be and if there is actually a biblical basis for them.

Comment: Please bring this old question into current site guidelines. Thanks. Resource for your convenience: [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that ***ideally*** the Christian life would be **fully** marked by the leading of the Spirit.  *(Don't get too nervous about this - God isn't a taskmaster - His will is [not oppressive](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2011:28,%20Romans%2013:9&version=NASB), contrary to popular belief.)*  Here is the Biblical basis for this argument:

The first is a statement from Jesus, our perfect example, our Rabbi of which we are to be disciples and immitators:

> “I can do nothing on My own initiative. As I hear, I judge; and My judgment is just, because I do not seek My own will, but the will of Him who sent Me." [***-John 5:30***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%205:30&version=NASB)

To clarify our calling as Christians, here is Paul's post-ascension teaching on the matter:

> and He died for all, so that they who live might no longer live for themselves, but for Him who died and rose again on their behalf. [***-2 Corinthians 5:15***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%205:15&version=NASB)

In contrast, one of the sins which condemned Saul was not inquiring of the Lord:

> So Saul died for his trespass which he committed against the Lord, because of the word of the Lord which he did not keep; and also because he asked counsel of a medium, making inquiry of it, **and did not inquire of the Lord**. Therefore He killed him and turned the kingdom to David the son of Jesse. [***-1 Chronicles 10:13-14***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Chronicles%2010:13-14&version=NASB)

There are many other passages, but this should suffice.  Our mindset needs to be: 100% devotion to the leading of the Spirit, 0% devotion to living for our own purposes.

Now, ***practically*** speaking, there are times to rest, times to fellowship, times to have a drink, times to read, times to gaze at the stars, and so on.

**At what point should you just make a decision?**  Well, technically, at ***every*** point.  Everything you do, whether "led by the Spirit" or "led by your flesh" is technically "a decision", so in every case you should "just make a decision" -- with the understanding that in every case you should "be sensitive to the leading of the Spirit", if He is leading, and in every case you should "guard against the lusts of the flesh".

Comment: Let me know if you would like to see any additional Scripture references added.

Comment: @Jas31 – I like where you are going with this.  I once heard a pithy statement that said ‘Jesus is a Shepard but he does not direct you to which tuft of grass to chew on.’ I thought there is some wisdom in that as we do not see people in the Bible praying about when they should wake up, or any detail like this. When is it lack of faith to always pray about things, without having the confidence that God has given us a brain to decide. Having said this I probably am probably the pot calling the kettle black.